# Perform a get action with asp.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm working on asp.net core 2.1

Now we have views with classes like:

[image]

Each view have their own class, my class have `OnGet()` method, so I think this is a Get request when page load. But I put breakpoint into that method and never hits.

I want to do a simple get to do a SelectList into my view like:

```
public void OnGet()
        {

            var roles = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();

            List<SelectListItem> item = roles.ConvertAll(a =>
            {
                return new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = a.Id.ToString(),
                    Value = a.Name.ToString(),
                };
            }).ToList();

            var vm = new ApplicationRoleViewModel();

            vm.RolesToUser = roles
                         .Select(a => new SelectListItem()
                         {
                             Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                             Text = a.Name
                         })
                         .ToList();


            return ;
        }
```

View:

```
 <select asp-for="RoleId" asp-items="@Model.RolesToUser">
        <option>Please select one</option>
    </select>
```

But it always throw null because it never returns results from `OnGet()`, my question is. How can I do a simple get action in this new structure of views! Regards
Full Code:

AssignRoleToUser.cshtml.cs

```
namespace Security.WebUi.Pages
{
    public class AssignRoleToUserModel : PageModel
    {

        private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;

        public AssignRoleToUserModel(
             RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager
            )
        {
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }


        public void OnGet()
        {

            var roles = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();

            List<SelectListItem> item = roles.ConvertAll(a =>
            {
                return new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = a.Id.ToString(),
                    Value = a.Name.ToString(),
                };
            }).ToList();

            var vm = new ApplicationRoleViewModel();

            vm.RolesToUser = roles
                         .Select(a => new SelectListItem()
                         {
                             Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                             Text = a.Name
                         })
                         .ToList();


            return ;
        }


    }
}
```

View:

```
@page
@model Security.Dto.ViewModels.ApplicationRoleViewModel


    <h4>Assign role to user</h4>
    <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <select asp-for="RoleId" asp-items="@Model.RolesToUser">
        <option>Please select one</option>
    </select>

    <br />


@section Scripts {

}
```

ApplicationRoleViewModel:

```
namespace Security.Dto.ViewModels
{
    public class ApplicationRoleViewModel
    {
        public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> RolesToUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `asp-for="RoleId"` I suppose `RoleId` is a property from a class. Must be the class like ` asp-for="Role"`.

Comment: @CalC I update all my code

Comment: I update my question with full code @Llazar

Comment: What is the `RoleId`? `asp-for` needs a Model.

Comment: `RoleId`it's the value of viewmodel : `ApplicationRoleViewModel` @Llazar

Comment: If your model is `ApplicationRoleViewModel` then add it to the taghelper `asp-for`.

Comment: Can you explain more? I'm confuse there, I already have a model declared in view, that's why I'm using `RoleId` in `asp-for` @Llazar

Comment: Check this link to see how select taghelper works https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1#the-select-tag-helper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a Razor Page, apparently. With Razor Pages, the model for the view is the `PageModel` itself, i.e. your codebehind file. In your `OnGet` action you're newing up some random class, and setting a property on that, but then it just gets garbage collected. Instead, you should have this `RolesToUser` property on your `PageModel` itself, and set that:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RolesToUser { get; set; }

...

public void OnGet()
{
    var roles = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();

    RolesToUser = roles.Select(a => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = a.Id.ToString(),
        Text = a.Name
    }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: But when page load it never hit `OnGet` method, any idea why that happen?

Comment: You're loading a different page, then. Check your URL/routes. `OnGet` is the default for a Razor Page, so if that's never getting called, you're not hitting that page at all.